# Можно ли вернуть web страницу с вложенным json?

Tags: json, node.js, express

Здравствуйте, мне нужно сделать, чтобы любые изменения или перемещения елементов на странице , сохранялись (записывались в конфиг). И при следующем  открытии страницы они оставались на тех же местах, где были при прошлом открытии.  Запись в конфиг я сделал через ajax (при изменении елемента данные отсылаются на специальный метод который пишет в конфиг).

Теперь не могу понять, как сделать, чтобы при открытии страницы снова, эти данные в нее попали. Есть вариант снова делать ajax запрос на специальный метод, получить json и расствить свойства елементам.

Но нет ли способа более правильного, без ajax? Чтобы сам express отрендерил страничку и вложил в нее этот json? И как его получить на странице?

Как сделать что-то типо такого но чтобы работало? )

```
app.use('/page' , function ( req, res) {

  fs.readFile('./config.json', 'utf8', function read(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }

    res.json({ elementsParameters:  data  });
    res.render('page', { title:  'express'} );
  })

  });
```

Сервер Node.js на express, а контейнер ejs.

Comment: Вы можете включить JSON в страницу как обычный javascript-объект внутри HTML-контейнера <script>. Увы, не работал с Node.js, но судя по Вашему коду, это будет как-то так: res.render('page', { title:  'express', elementsParameters:  data} );, и останется вывести elementsParameters внутри вида page как строку встроенного javascript-кода.

Comment: Благодарю, работает! В клиенте вот такой код получился

 " var data =<%-JSON.stringify(elementsParameters)%> ; "
  " var parsedData = JSON.parse(data); "

Comment: а можно просто, так : 'var data = <%-elementsParameters %>;'